# Deployment of war file to tomcat fails in heroku with HttpResponseException

Tags: java, tomcat, heroku

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Service Unavailable

```
   at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.utils.RestClient.handleResponse(RestClient.java:170)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.utils.RestClient.post(RestClient.java:125)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.endpoints.Builds.build(Builds.java:71)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.BuildsDeployer.deploySlug(BuildsDeployer.java:105)    
 at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.Deployer.createAndReleaseSlug(Deployer.java:121)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:80)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:64)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:68)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.WarApp.deploy(WarApp.java:33)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeployWar.main(DeployWar.java:116)
```

Comment: What command are you running? Are you using the Maven plugin? What version?

Comment: Hi, am doing "Deployment with the Heroku CLI".  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment#deployment-with-the-heroku-cli

Comment: Are you still getting the error?

Comment: Actually it seems like there was build issue running during the time i was trying to deploy. Now it actually works fine. Thanks.